# how to add the bootstrap label in selection tag with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-select2

I have the legecy project. Now I need to add the bootstrap label to the select tag.

like

`<option value = "id-value> file name (bootstrap label here)</option>`

Comment: can you give more information on this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ucLvjvkn/117/

Comment: check this link, plz

Comment: Now I need to add the bootstrap label to the select tag >> what does this mean? I'm not able to relate this statement to the jsfiddle

Comment: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/bELxVw  check this link, it's in jquery. I have to do the same in angularjs